# How to post image using Arduino HTTPClient

Tags: arduino, httpclient, esp32

I am using arduino HTTPClient to do the post request in ESP32. Can anyone help me with the part where I will be able to post an image file along with some data.

The below code works perfectly fine with only sending user_name and image_type-

```
#include <HTTPClient.h>

http.begin("https://www.somelink.com/post-image");

http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

String httpRequestData = "user_name=Shidhartha&image_type=Outdoor";

int httpResponseCode = http.POST(httpRequestData);
if(httpResponseCode > 0){
  String response = http.getString();
  Serial.println(response);
}else{
  Serial.print("Error on sending POST: ");
  Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using ESP32. You may refer to this [link](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-cam-post-image-photo-server/)